# Change entire object in ng-repeat function AngularJs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Hello I have a questions on ng-repeat on Angularand function for change value.
I have this `ng-repeat` that cycling a ObjectArray and have a button for reset value.

```
<div ng-repeat="element in data.elements">
   <button ng-click="reset(element)" >reset</button>
</div>
```

Where `data.elements` is array of objects example:

```
[{id:1, name:"element1"},{id:2, name : "element2"}];
```

In my `Controller` I set function Reset in `$scope` that should do a copy of object passed to an default object:

```
$scope.reset = function(el){
  $scope.defaultObject = {id:500, name:"default"};
  el = angular.copy($scope.defaultObject);
}
```

But doesn't work, but if I do:

```
$scope.reset = function(el){
      $scope.defaultObject = {id:500, name:"default"};
      el.name = $scope.defaultObject.name;
    }
```

It work.
So I would like  that when I do (in this example):

```
el = angular.copy($scope.defaultObject);
```

have the object `el` equals to object `$scope.defaultObject` my question is, Can i copy entire object without cycling all properties?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I correctly clone a JavaScript object?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/728360/how-do-i-correctly-clone-a-javascript-object)

Comment: thanks I will see link!

Comment: I see this link, but "Can I copy entire object without cycling all properties?" in this post seems that do a cycle of property of object and assign this to object.

Comment: You're passing an object to the reset function, then you're overwriting this object. That's it, nothing happens because it won't affect the original object, which is in the `data.elements` array.

You need to use a different approach. Track the element by its index (`ng-repeat="$index,element in data.elements`), then amend `data.elements[$index]`.

Comment: @JeremyThille right! thank you!

Comment: I'll write a proper answer later. I'm at work right now

Comment: `angular.copy(el, $scope.defaultObject)` ? https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.copy

Comment: thankyou jeremy, in your answer can you explain even why if I set property of element it work? thankyou

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're passing an object to the reset function, then you're overwriting this object. That's it, nothing happens because it won't affect the original object, which is in the `data.elements` array.

You need to use a different approach. Track the element by its index :

```
<div ng-repeat="element in data.elements track by index">
     <button ng-click="reset(index)" >reset</button>
</div>
```

...then amend `data.elements[index]`:

```
$scope.reset = function(index){
  $scope.data.elements[index] = {id:500, name:"default"};
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but can I ask you why if I modify a object property it work?

Comment: I don't understand the question, what do you mean?

Comment: That if I do `reset(element);` and in reset function I do: `element.name = "test"`; it change corretly the value.

Comment: Oh yes, it will update the `element` object, just because you pass it to the reset function. But it has no effect on the original element, which is in `data.elements`. All you do is give some object to a function, then modify the object. This doesn't have any other effect whatsoever on the original object, it is a new instance.

Comment: Thankyou for explain!

Answer (score 0):

are you saying, your updated object does not reflect on the UI? you can try forcing the scope update by running `$scope.$apply()` after you have assigned the object.

Comment: No, I can't call $scope.$apply because it force a digest, and if the last not is finished, make error.

Comment: @LorenzoBerti, to avoid an error you can use $timeout(() => $scope.$apply()) .